# What Materials and Load cells are suitable for a Medical Weighing device?

Tags: materials, biomedical-engineering, medical-devices

I'm creating a medical weighing scale for immobile patients for my final year project in college. The weighing scale is a flat surface that can be slid underneath the patient.

I'm at a standpoint as to which load cells to use. A prototype version will suffice, so the ideal thickness of 10mm to 20mm for the weighing scale itself isn't a necessity by any means.

Material selection is also an area that I've found struggle with. Especially when considering rigidity and flexibility of the device.

[image]

Comment: Slide sensors under each bed leg, measure mass then add patient and measure again. Then do maths. These exist and are used for trucks…

Comment: Issues I can see with what you are trying to do is such a device would best be in a flat horizontal position. How are you going to account for flexing & curvature of the device, different types of mattresses: air, spring etc. & the different levels of support they offer. Or would the device be placed under a mattress & if so how do you get it there with the patient still in bed?

Comment: There are so many different approaches to this problem it's difficult to recommend just one.  The whole point of engineering once you're released into the real world is that -- unlike homework problems -- there are _lots and lots_ of answers that are good enough, not just one that'll get you an 'A', ten that'll get you a 'B', etc.  Do a search of all the force sensors that you can find, and see which ones look like likely candidates.  Then go from there.

Comment: To further explain the project, I'm required to design a device that is portable, provides faster treatment time, and is dignifying to the patient. The concept design is pretty much set at this point. The device is slid underneath the patient (above the mattress). The project is at a very early stage of its process, I'm struggling with issues such as accounting for flexibility and curvature of the device, what sections are required to be flexible/rigid, and how many load cells should be used in order to calculate the weight accurately. Any advice or input will be greatly appreciated.